# CORS requests in electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am developing a react application (chat app) using electron js (for desktops) I want to make Http requests to certain websites, to get URL metadata (opengraph, schema.org, twitterCard, etc). This cannot be done without disabling the webSecurity in electronJS.

a) is it a good idea to disable webSecurity in electron JS ? since users can send others pretty much anything ?

b) I have managed to achieve this using electron net package. I used it in react (renderer process) and it works smoothly, no need to disable webSecurity. however when a invalid URL is provided it throws an exception in main process (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) which pops a error dialog box. is there a way to catch this exception in the renderer process?

below is how I used electron net package.

```
const {net} = window.require('electron').remote

function ScrapeMeta(url) {
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
        url: url,
        timeout: 2000
    };
    const request = net.request(options)
    request.on('response', (response) => {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function (d) {
            body += d;
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                ParseMeta(body)
                    .then(meta => resolve(meta))
                    .catch(err => reject(err))
            } else {
                reject("request failed with " + response.statusCode);
            }
        })
    })
    request.end();
})
return promise;
```

}

What is the best way to achieve this. thanks.

Comment: How do you load those items ? Aren't  ClientRequest ( https://electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request) can do what you need ?

Comment: thank you for the fast reply, I have edited the question with how I used the net package